# Meteor bundle cannot run command: node main.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, meteor, fibers

I have run `meteor build` in one of my meteorJS apps and then extracted the bundle and After running `npm install` in programs/server
I face an error when I try to run `node main.js` in root fold

I have tried to search for npm package called topologies to add it but found none

I try to run `node main.js` but it fails and throws an error

I have expected the app to run but instead I get this error:

```
node main.js
E:\Projects\elibrary\production\nn\bundle\programs\server\node_modules\fibers\fi
bers.js:90
return fn.apply(this, arguments);
^

Error: Cannot find module ‘…/topologies/read_preference’
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object. (E:\Projects\elibrary\production\nn\bundle\programs\se
rver\npm\node_modules\meteor\npm-mongo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\wireprotoco
l\shared.js:3:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
at Object.Module._extensions…js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The missing file appears to be part of the mongo driver.   The solution may be version related - what Meteor version are you using? and what mongo version?

Comment: Please tell us what your node version on your local dev is using `meteor node -v` and on your server using `node -v`

Comment: Try to run `node main.js` from /bundle path. Have you done it?

Comment: `node -v` returns `10.15.3`
`meteor node -v` returns v8.15.1
I am currently trying on my local machine

Comment: My meteor version is 1.8.1
and running `mongo` in root directory returns  `MongoDB server version: 4.0.4`
I am trying to run the commands in windows using the command prompt